# what is the advantage to use Spline to represent curve?

Tags: graphics, geometry, computational-geometry, spline

Often hear about curve modeled using spline. What's the advantage of using spline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spline data consists of control points and weights that are related to each other (a point on a spline depends on the coordinates and weights several neighboring control points).  Curve data would either be a large set of closely spaced points to approximate the curve (expensive to store, where spline data is sparse), or an equation which might take a lot of horsepower to solve for y from a given x.  Splines can be cheaply computed and subdivided/interpolated to achieve the desired precision but a curve of explicit points loses precision without having weight information.  Splines are also really useful in vector art (think Flash or Adobe Illustrator) and 3D graphics because you can intuitively drag a few control points around to get exactly the curve you want instead of having to move a ton of individual curve points.